# UITableViewCell unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: xcode, uitableview, button, segue

I'm creating a table view and custom view for my UITableView. Basically I have FirstViewController with table view and CustomTableViewCell. In custom cell, I had link all the controls to header and implements in the file which superclass with UITableViewCell. I'm creating a button, and want to programatically using "instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier" for more flexibility in future. Here's come a problem :

**Button being initialized**

```
[self.playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(NavigationMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

**NavigateMethod**

```
 UIViewController *secondViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
 [(FirstViewController*) presentViewController:secondViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Because everything is in UITableViewCell instead of UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You're breaking Model View Controller methodology here... In FirstViewController you should have

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    MYCustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[MYCustomTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; // might not be UITableViewCellStyleDefault
        [cell.playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(navigationMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    }


    // all indexPath based tableViewCell changes here

    return cell;
}
```

Now `-(void)navigationMethod` can go in your FirstViewController class also. Which will allow you to call

```
[self presentViewController:secondViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

or

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:secondViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Just to add in as well.. unrecognised selector sent to instance means in this case the method `NavigationMethod` is not found in your UITableViewCell subclass